# Matching length of each column of csv in bash

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, awk, cut

```
data.dat:
001,Sam,SA
002,Tom,SA
003,Lara,WI
004,Mhd,Pak

lookup.dat:
p_id,3
p_name,3
p_team,2
```

How can i  write a shell script to validate the lenght of each field in data.dat by checking the respective lenths of the columns in lookup file.

if error(length not matching) as in case of p_id 003 & 004
display the record no and the column name.

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you are trying to validate and what you are trying to validate to. This is confusing.

Comment: Please add sample output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: The point of having a delimiter like a comma is to allow variable-width fields. If you're going to require fixed-width columns, just use, e.g., `001SamSA`

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
source <(sed 's/,/=/' lookup.dat)
while IFS=',' read -r id name team; do
  (( i++ ))
  line="$id $name $team, line $i : different size"
  [ ${#id} == $p_id ] || echo "$line id"
  [ ${#name} == $p_name ] || echo "$line name"
  [ ${#team} == $p_team ] || echo "$line team"
done < data.dat
```

Output :

```
003 Lara WI, line 3 : different size name
004 Mhd Pak, line 4 : different size team
```

The loop compares for each lines the size of fields with the sizes referenced in lookup.dat.

If size differs the field is printed with line number.

**Update :**

As suggested, i added `-r` to the read command to prevent backslash interpretation while reading datas.

Variable names have been hard coded for better readability. If number and/or type of variables/datas can change, prefer the Ed Morton answer.

Comment: Since the shell is not designed to do text processing, that will be an order of magnitude slower than an equivalent awk script. Also the names and number of the variables in the script are tightly coupled to the input data - consider an array/loop instead of a list of hard-coded variable names. It will also delete backslash chars (you're missing the `-r` arg to read) and can have other unexpected effects depending on the input data. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice.

Comment: Thanks for the link, an interesting discussion... In this case if we  consider that id, name or team won't reasonably contain  backslashes it should do the trick.

Comment: and as long as some prankster doesn't modify `lookup.dat` to contain `rm -rf /` or anything else :-). It's always dangerous to blindly execute your input data - hence the whole `declare` vs `eval` (aka mis-spelled `evil`) discussion.

Comment: I agree in substrance and i'll remember your observations next time. Although shell scripts can be helpful in a readable manner in simple situations when the context is under control.

Answer (score 2):

Making a whole bunch of assumptions about what your input data represents and what you are trying to do, this MAY be what you want:

```
awk -F, '
NR==FNR { name[NR]=$1; reqLength[NR]=$2; next }
{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (length($i) != reqLength[i]) print "Ruh-roh:", FNR, name[i] }
' lookup.dat data.dat
Ruh-roh: 3 p_name
Ruh-roh: 4 p_team
```